# How to create a PDF file from a JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, pdf

I am developing a web application and when I want to add some functionality I find a problem:

-I offer to my clients the possibility of see a page called "Product details" with: the description of this product, product´s name, an image of the product... and I want to give them the chance of download a PDF file with (more or less) the same data.

The problem is that I am using Servlets and JSP so if I want to create a PDF from my HTML page I must take the "final" page.

So my question is: 
-Is there a way to create a PDF automatically from a JSP in Java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java

Comment: use iText for pdf in java